# How to group rows that match one of two conditions?

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to write a macro to group rows that are filled with one of two colors (white/RGB(255,255,255) or pale yellow/RBG(255, 255, 238)). But when I run my macro, it only groups the pale yellow rows.

Fixed code (thanks to @Vityata) :

```
Option Explicit

Sub RowGrouper()
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each rng In Range(Cells(10, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)).Cells
    If rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) Or rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 238) Then
        rng.Rows.Group
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

The end result should look like this:

[image]

I appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this:

```
rng.Interior.ColorIndex = rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
```

Write this:

```
rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
```

Comment: Wow. I am embarrassed I did not see that. Totally tunnel visioned there. Thank you so much!

Comment: @CATSandCATSandCATS - nothing to be embarrassed of. Glad I could help :)

Comment: And to think I just completely rewrote the solution instead, ha! X(

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot - I find it easier to just outline the *whole* range first before grouping.

**I see that Vityata found the typo, but I *have* to post my solution anyways! :)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub RowGrouper()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastRow As Long

    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 10 To lastRow
        For j = i To lastRow
            If Cells(j, 1).Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 255, 255) And Cells(j, 1).Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 255, 238) Then
                If j <> i Then
                    Rows(i & ":" & j - 1).Rows.Group
                    i = j
                    Exit For
                Else
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next

End Sub
```

[image: img1]

Comment: I love it. This is a much more elegant solution than what I was doing. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me!